# Could someone please tell me which font is used in this image?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Could someone please tell me which font is used in this image?

UPD (Ilan: better background + other letters)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use this tool to find it : https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: where have you looked?  have you used What the font?

Answer (score 3):

The font is [SLIM TONY](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fenotype/slim-tony/regular/glyphs.html), authors used some variants of the letters - look at the link for exact matches.

[image]